# Run Heroku local dev on Windows (PHP buildpack)

Tags: php, windows, heroku

I'm trying to configure Heroku Local on a Windows 10 machine.

Composer, php, git, and heroku are installed fine, and my procfile look like this:

```
dev: vendor\bin\heroku-php-nginx -i php.conf.ini -c nginx.conf.php
```

but when i try to run, give me this error:

```
dev.1   |  'vendor\bin\heroku-php-nginx' is not recognized as an internal 
dev.1   |  or external command, operable program or batch file.
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  null
Exited with exit code 1
```

seens like windows can't run the bash file of heroku-php-nginx?

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/blob/master/bin/heroku-php-nginx

What i can do?